# LINQPad "failed to initialize" on installation?

Tags: linqpad

The install is going through just fine. I am unable to launch it post-install. I get an error saying 'Application failed to initialize properly. (0x0000135). Click OK to terminate."

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like LINQPad thinks it's too good to be un-installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May sound like a silly question, but do you have the .NET Framework installed?

Re: [this](http://www.mynethelp.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=2) article

If the problem persists, you should contact the creators of Linqpad - here's their uservoice page: http://linqpad.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so silly that I did not think of it.